# React Native get initial state from async componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i want to displaying state value to render() from async function that already called from componenDidMount, but in the first execution component it returned undefined, for second attempt it showing correct data

this is my state **this.state.userData**

my question is, what is priority processed function between render() and componentDidMount()?

This is my code

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    store.get('userData').then((val) => {
        if(typeof val != 'undefined'){
            this.setState({'userData':val});
        }
    }).done();
},
render: function() {
    return(
        <View>
              <Text>{this.state.userData}</Text> // displaying undefined
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: it seems code working as it supposed to. Main thread is not blocked using promise object(this is what promise obj for). After store.get(..) called render function is called and it looks for userData but it doesn't exist in first render since setState({'userData':val}) hasn't worked and caused second render. If you add this state in getInıtıalState() with '' empty string you won't see undefined. You are trying to solve undefined in componentdid mount but there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking.

As I understand it: you want to execute a function to set data before render() is called. 
In that case: take a look at lifecycle methods -> [link](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/). It explains quite nicely that you can use componentWillMount() before render is called.
[image]

However: this doesn't guarantee that you have your data before render is called. I would suggest you set an additional state variable to know when the async call is complete and before that just call a loading spinner.

Something like:

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
  loading: true
 }
}
```

in your function:

```
this.setState({userData:val, loading: false});
```

render:

```
render() {
if(this.state.loading){
  return( <ActivityIndicator size='large' style={{height:80}} />
}
else{
 return(
     <View>
           <Text>{this.state.userData}</Text> // displaying undefined
     </View>
 );
}
```

(should only give an idea - code is improvised.. but should solve the undefined problem)
have fun

Comment: Thanks for your information
I updated componentDidMount to componentWillMount But in my case, i need to waiting the result because i use promises function to get value and it makes result undefined at the first attempt component

Comment: So why not divert the render to something different until you have the result from "store"? In that case you would be sure not to get undefined